# Database Seeding laravel create 50 users and attach a relationship to each user

Tags: php, laravel

I have use

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($user) {
        $user->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());
    });
```

inside run function in  DatabaseSeeder

when I execute `php artisan db:seed`
the output is below

```
Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

   BadMethodCallException  : Call to undefined method App\User::posts()

  at /home/ahmed/myDesgin/laravelApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50
    46|      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
    47|      */
    48|     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
    49|     {
  > 50|         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    51|             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
    52|         ));
    53|     }
    54| }

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException("posts")
      /home/ahmed/myDesgin/laravelApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:36

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "posts", [])
      /home/ahmed/myDesgin/laravelApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1618

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

what is the cause of this problem and how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure will it help you or not. But you can try to create users and their dummy post with relationship like that:

```
factory(User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {
    $user->posts()->saveMany(factory(Posts::class, 5)->make());
});
```

Comment: Replace with your code and let him know what happens

Answer (score 0):

this is my user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

and below database seeds DatabaseSeeder.php

```
 <?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
      /*   $this->call([
            UsersTableSeeder::class,
        ]); */
        factory(User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->posts()->saveMany(factory(Posts::class, 5)->make());
        });
    }
}
```